# How to get the UID Authentication from Firebase in Flutter and save in Firestore

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-authentication

I'm trying to get the `uid`, but it always returns the `uid` of the previously created account.

`createUserWithEmailAndPassword`  does not execute the login after being completed.
So it should be returning the `uid` correctly, right?

Below are 2 pictures of the database and `Authentication`, as well as the code.

```
    Future _singUp() async {
    final User? user = auth.currentUser;
    final uid = user!.uid;

    try {
      await FirebaseAuth.instance.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(
        email: _emailController.text,
        password: _passwordController.text,
      );

      await FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('users').add({
        'email': _emailController.text,
        'name': _nameController.text,
        'Id_usuario': uid
      });
    } on FirebaseAuthException catch (e) {
      _handleSingUpError(e);
    }
  }
```

[image: Image 1]

[image: Image 2]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you use createUserWithEmailAndPassword it will return a UserCredential as a result, you can use that to update your user variable, so in code it would be something like this:

```dart
UserCredential result = await FirebaseAuth.instance.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email: email, password: password);
User? user = result.user;
```